# Question on continuity and intermediate value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : [0,1]\to ℝ$ be continuous  and such that $f(0)=f(1)$. Prove that there exists a point $c \in [0, \frac{1}{2} ]$ such that $f(c)=f(c+\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: This has been answered many times. Try to search for it on this site.

Comment: As others have pointed out, this question has been answered multiple times. A hint would be to observe what is special about $1/2$ in this context. It may also help you to set $f(0) = f(1) = a$ and $f(1/2) = b$ to create more useful relations without missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**: suppose $g(x)=f(x+\frac{1}{2})-f(x)$. Now use intermediate value theorem.
Also you can prove it by contradiction suppose equality doesn't hold.